# How do I block orkut.com on a shared PC?

Tags: networking, browser-addons, web, safe-browsing

My PC is also used by my son who has this habit of overspending time on orkut.com
How can I limit his time using orkut?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the type of computer you are running? Is it Windows, Linux, or Mac? Do you want to restrict access completely or allow access but limit it in some way?

Comment: How about ask him NOT to vist the website and if he does you punish him?  Modify the hosts file to redirect all traffic requests to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Besides the suggestions below, you can also check your router's configuration. Many provide an option to block sites by keywords, domain names, IPs etc., completely or according to a preset schedule (whenever your son is allowed to sit at the PC).

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Instructions

1. Open your firewall's configuration utility. Steps to do this will
   vary depending on your specific firewall. For example, if you use
   the Windows Firewall (a permanent fixture of Windows XP, Windows
   Vista and Windows 7), you would enter the Windows Control Panel and
   open the "Windows Firewall" icon.
2. Select the "Settings" option in your firewall configuration utility.
   Some firewalls may call this the "Options" or even "Configure" menu
   option. This will bring up a list of programs and sites that are
   currently blocked from access, as well as a list of programs and
   sites that are currently allowed access to your network connection.
3. Select the "Add" button and add the URL of the website you don't
   want users of your computer to be able to access.
4. Click "OK." The URL of the website will appear on the list on screen
   and that website will be blocked from access on your computer by the
   firewall.

### Method 2

If you are using Windows you can do this via Internet Explorer:

1. Click the Start button, click  Control Panel, type Internet options
   in the search box, and then click  Internet Options.
2. Click the Security tab, click a  Restricted sites and then click 
   Sites.
3. To add a site, type the URL into the Add this website to the zone
   box, and then click  Add.

### Method 3

1. Access Internet Explorer from your computer.
2. Choose "Tools" at the top of the screen. Select "Internet Options"
   from the drop-down menu.
3. Click the "Content" tab in the Internet Options menu. Scroll down to
   the second menu option, "Content Advisor," and click. Wait for the
   new menu to appear.
4. Click "Settings" within the Content Advisor menu. When the
   "Supervisor Password Required" dialog box appears, enter your
   Windows 7 password into this field and press "Enter."
5. Click the "Approved Sites" tab at the top of the screen. Wait for
   the words "Allow This Website," along with an empty dialog, box to
   appear.
6. Enter the full URL of the site you wish to block access to in the
   empty dialog box under "Allow This Website." Check "Never."
   ("Always" is the other option.)
7. Click "Apply" to confirm that you are blocking access to the chosen
   website. Click "OK" when you get a message confirming the change has
   gone into effect. The website is now blocked by your Windows 7
   firewall.

**Also you could try Windows Family Safety.** It provides more options.

Answer (score 0):

In Mozilla, you can use the add-on [leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/?src=userprofile).
With it you can set up what times of the week the Orkut is open. Or you can block it permanently and/or without permission to change.
Since it works only on Mozilla, you may uninstall other browsers.